# Simulation of transimpedance amplifier in LTspice

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, ltspice, transimpedance, transimpedance-amplifier

I am trying to simulate a circuit that is presented in a [research paper](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BR_SSCM_1_2023.pdf) by Dr Behzad Razavi. I am using LTspice for the simulation (please see the attached image and netlist for the circuit).

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I am using the [32nm library](https://web.archive.org/web/20221207192451fw_/https://ptm.asu.edu/latest.html) for the simulation.

When I do the noise analysis, I get a value of input-referred noise of 93 μA/sqr(H), which differs (and too much compared to 10 pA/sqr(H) from what is reported in the paper. Is my calculation of the noise method correct?

[image: Input referred noise]

Moreover, the paper claims a bandwidth of 11 GHz, but I am not achieving 1.14 GHz in my simulation. Why there is so much discrepancy?

[image: Ac analysis]

DC analysis shows that the current mirror does not supply a sufficient current of 1 mA to drive the M1 and M3 MOSFET stage. When I disconnect the current mirror and directly connect to the ground, about one milliampere of current flows, as also given in the research paper. How can I make sure that the current mirror is not loaded when it's connected to the M1 and M3 MOSFET stage?

I was wondering if anyone could provide some recommendations or insights on how I might resolve these issues.

**Circuit Netlist:**

```
* D:\PDK_demo\Behzad_Razavi.asc
C1 N004 0 75f
I1 0 N004 PULSE(12u 0 0 1p 1p 1n 2n) AC 1
M2 N003 N004 0 0 NMOS l=30n w=10u
V1 Vdd 0 0.95
R1 Vdd N003 1k
M1 N002 N003 0 Vdd PMOS l=30n w=10u
M3 N002 Vb out Vdd PMOS l=30n w=10u
M4 Vdd N001 N002 Vdd PMOS l=30n w=20u
M5 Vdd N001 P001 Vdd PMOS l=30n w=5u
I2 N001 0 0.25m
R2 P001 N001 1k
R3 out N004 1k
R4 out 0 1k
M6 Vdd out 0 0 NMOS l=30n w=5u
V2 Vb 0 0.3
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\LTspice\lib\cmp\standard.mos
;noise V(out) I1 oct 10 100 100G
.include 32nm.txt
;ac dec 51 1 100G
;op 1
.tran 0.01u
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: M1 and M3 say PMOS, but they use NMOS symbols in the schematic. This is probably not an issue (the SPICE netlist is what matters, not the schematic symbols), but should be changed for clarity!

Comment: Indeed, are you sure you're PMOSes in that long tailed pair?

Comment: can you also copy the .asc file? I'd like to play with this,

Comment: Hearth, I have updated the schematic. 
@Designalog, please Find the schematic link here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lgGe60gE2wbX5p3HyjHLkD1VBwAtbwNs?usp=drive_link

Comment: The paper explicitly states that M7 and M8 bodies should be tied to their sources. The image in the paper also shows dotted lines to illustrate this. I don’t know if that’s your main problem, but it’s definitely a discrepancy.

Comment: @SteKulov, thank you for pointing this out. I made this change, but connecting the body to the source in the simulation has no effect. However, if I replace the M4 M5 current mirror with an ideal current source, I see an improvement of almost 8 GHz bandwidth with reduced gain.